# Можно ли отправить файл на почту в c+++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

в принципе у меня код нормально работает, но я бы хотел добатить код чтобы отправить рисунок или типо того. вот сам код

```css
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit2.h"
//#include <IdAttachmenFile.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm2 *Form2;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner)
 : TForm(Owner)
{

}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
 TIdSMTP* SMTP = new TIdSMTP(Form2);
SMTP->Host = "smtp.yandex.ru";
SMTP->Port = 465;
SMTP->Username = "Anonim@yandex.ru";
SMTP->Password = "secret";
SMTP->HeloName="HelloName"; //Any Latin name.

//this must be used for SSL
TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL* IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 = new TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(NULL);
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1->Host = SMTP->Host;
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1->Port = SMTP->Port;
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1->DefaultPort = 0;
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1->SSLOptions->Method = sslvSSLv23;
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1->SSLOptions->Mode = sslmUnassigned;
SMTP->IOHandler = IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;

SMTP->UseTLS = utUseImplicitTLS;
SMTP->ReadTimeout = 15000;
SMTP->Connect();

if(SMTP->Connected())
{
TIdMessage* IdMessage = new TIdMessage(Form2);
IdMessage->Clear();
//IdMessage->ContentType = "text/html";
//IdMessage->CharSet = "windows-1251";
IdMessage->Subject = L"SUBJECT";
IdMessage->Body->Text = L"ANOnim!";
IdMessage->From->Address = SMTP->Username;
IdMessage->From->Name = "ANONIM";
IdMessage->Recipients->EMailAddresses ="anonnim@yandex.ru";

SMTP->Send(IdMessage);
IdMessage->Free();
}
else
{
ShowMessage("Dont have connect");
}

SMTP->Disconnect();
SMTP->Free();
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1->Free();
}
```

Comment: Я использую CSmtp: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28806/SMTP-Client, там уже есть работа с вложениями, из примера `mail.AddAttachment("c:\\test.exe");`. Или ты про вставку изображение в текст письма с использованием html?

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку! Нет, не HTML,